# An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.EvaluateException' occurred in System.Data.dll Additional information: Cannot find column [Name]

Tags: c#, csv

I wanted to do a simple search box from textbox on Visual Studio, where you will enter a certain letter or keyword so you can search/filter for an existing **contract** from a .csv.

And then it will show up on the dataGridView1. I parsed the .csv and created a datasource from it called "tbl".

Now every time I input something on my txtBoxSearch this error shows up.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.EvaluateException'
> occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Cannot find
> column [Name]

These are the parts associated with the error

```
private void txtBoxSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataView DV = new DataView(tbl);
    DV.RowFilter = string.Format("Approved Contracts LIKE '%{0}%'", txtBoxSearch.Text);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = DV;
}
```

This is where the error is-->

```
DV.RowFilter = string.Format("Approved Contracts LIKE '%{0}%'", txtBoxSearch.Text);
```

Here is my complete code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;




namespace Contract_Management_System
{
    public partial class frmMain : Form
    {
        DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
        string file = "Approved.csv";
        int colNum = 10;
        DataSet dataset;


        public frmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(file);
            string[] data_col = null;
            int x = 0;

            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                data_col = line.Split(',');

                if (x == 0)
                {
                    //header
                    for (int i = 0; i <= data_col.Count() - 1; i++)
                    {
                        tbl.Columns.Add(data_col[i]);
                    }
                    x++;
                }
                else
                {
                    //data
                    tbl.Rows.Add(data_col);
                }
            }
            dataGridView1.DataSource = tbl;

            DataGridViewButtonColumn createButtonColumn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
            createButtonColumn.Name = "Create Contract";
            createButtonColumn.Text = "Create";
            int columnIndex = 2;

            if (dataGridView1.Columns["Create Contract"] == null)
            {
                dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(columnIndex, createButtonColumn);
            }

            dataGridView1.CellClick += dataFromBAC_CellClick;

        }

        private void dataFromBAC_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns["Create Contract"].Index)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("Create!");
                //dataFromBAC.Rows.RemoveAt(this.dataFromBAC.SelectedRows[0].Index);
            }
        }

        private void txtBoxSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataView DV = new DataView(tbl);
            DV.RowFilter = string.Format("Name LIKE '%{0}%'", txtBoxSearch.Text);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = DV;
        }

        private void btnFromBAC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            fromBAC form2 = new fromBAC();
            form2.Visible = true;
        }

        private void btnPending_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Pending form4 = new Pending();
            form4.Visible = true;
        }

        private void btnEndNotif_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            End form3 = new End();
            form3.Visible = true;
        }

        private void btnFromAMO_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            fromAMO form5 = new fromAMO();
            form5.Visible = true;
        }

        private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 'complete code' block is different from your sample - it has:

```
DV.RowFilter = string.Format("Name LIKE '%{0}%'", txtBoxSearch.Text);
```

Which matches the exception

```
Additional information: Cannot find column [Name]
```

There would only be a column named 'Name' if there was a column in the csv with header 'Name'.  I'd suggest reviewing the csv and confirming the headers in there.  Also, do a debug log or dump of the column names as they are added - you may find that they are being added with quotes or spaces, so the actual column name in the data table is `["Name"]` or `[Name ]`

If you intend to filter on a column called `Approved Contracts` with a space in it, your actual filter line should be:

```
DV.RowFilter = string.Format("[Approved Contracts] LIKE '%{0}%'", txtBoxSearch.Text);
```

Comment: Oh, sorry for that! I forgot to edit that out, as I was editing my code at the same time.

Comment: Thanks! It worked, thank you so much for the help, I've been stuck on this one for about an hour.